# Using Calendar Heat Map. Not showing month or legend

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, cal-heatmap

I am using [this](https://github.com/DKirwan/calendar-heatmap) to create a heatmap. However the names of the months are getting hidden. When I do a browser search, it is finding the month name but not showing it on the browser.

```js
function calendarHeatmap() {
  // defaults
  var width = 750;
  var height = 110;
  var legendWidth = 150;
  var selector = 'body';
  var SQUARE_LENGTH = 11;
  var SQUARE_PADDING = 2;
  var MONTH_LABEL_PADDING = 6;
  var now = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
  var yearAgo = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'year').toDate();
  var startDate = null;
  var data = [];
  var max = null;
  var colorRange = ['#D8E6E7', '#218380'];
  var tooltipEnabled = true;
  var tooltipUnit = 'contribution';
  var legendEnabled = true;
  var onClick = null;
  var weekStart = 0; //0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday
  var locale = {
    months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    days: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    No: 'No',
    on: 'on',
    Less: 'Less',
    More: 'More'
  };

  // setters and getters
  chart.data = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return data; }
    data = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.max = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return max; }
    max = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.selector = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return selector; }
    selector = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.startDate = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return startDate; }
    yearAgo = value;
    now = moment(value).endOf('day').add(1, 'year').toDate();
    return chart;
  };

  chart.colorRange = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return colorRange; }
    colorRange = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.tooltipEnabled = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return tooltipEnabled; }
    tooltipEnabled = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.tooltipUnit = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return tooltipUnit; }
    tooltipUnit = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.legendEnabled = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return legendEnabled; }
    legendEnabled = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.onClick = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return onClick(); }
    onClick = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.locale = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return locale; }
    locale = value;
    return chart;
  };

  function chart() {

    d3.select(chart.selector()).selectAll('svg.calendar-heatmap').remove(); // remove the existing chart, if it exists

    var dateRange = d3.time.days(yearAgo, now); // generates an array of date objects within the specified range
    var monthRange = d3.time.months(moment(yearAgo).startOf('month').toDate(), now); // it ignores the first month if the 1st date is after the start of the month
    var firstDate = moment(dateRange[0]);
    if (max === null) { max = d3.max(chart.data(), function (d) { return d.count; }); } // max data value

    // color range
    var color = d3.scale.linear()
      .range(chart.colorRange())
      .domain([0, max]);

    var tooltip;
    var dayRects;

    drawChart();

    function drawChart() {
      var svg = d3.select(chart.selector())
        .style('position', 'relative')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap')
        .attr('height', height)
        .style('padding', '36px');

      dayRects = svg.selectAll('.day-cell')
        .data(dateRange);  //  array of days for the last yr

      dayRects.enter().append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'day-cell')
        .attr('width', SQUARE_LENGTH)
        .attr('height', SQUARE_LENGTH)
        .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(countForDate(d)); })
        .attr('x', function (d, i) {
          var cellDate = moment(d);
          var result = cellDate.week() - firstDate.week() + (firstDate.weeksInYear() * (cellDate.weekYear() - firstDate.weekYear()));
          return result * (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING);
        })
        .attr('y', function (d, i) {
          return MONTH_LABEL_PADDING + formatWeekday(d.getDay()) * (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING);
        });

      if (typeof onClick === 'function') {
        dayRects.on('click', function (d) {
          var count = countForDate(d);
          onClick({ date: d, count: count});
        });
      }

      if (chart.tooltipEnabled()) {
        dayRects.on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
          tooltip = d3.select(chart.selector())
            .append('div')
            .attr('class', 'day-cell-tooltip')
            .html(tooltipHTMLForDate(d))
            .style('left', function () { return Math.floor(i / 7) * SQUARE_LENGTH + 'px'; })
            .style('top', function () {
              return formatWeekday(d.getDay()) * (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING) + MONTH_LABEL_PADDING * 2 + 'px';
            });
        })
        .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
          tooltip.remove();
        });
      }

      if (chart.legendEnabled()) {
        var colorRange = [color(0)];
        for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
          colorRange.push(color(max / i));
        }

        var legendGroup = svg.append('g');
        legendGroup.selectAll('.calendar-heatmap-legend')
            .data(colorRange)
            .enter()
          .append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap-legend')
            .attr('width', SQUARE_LENGTH)
            .attr('height', SQUARE_LENGTH)
            .attr('x', function (d, i) { return (width - legendWidth) + (i + 1) * 13; })
            .attr('y', height + SQUARE_PADDING)
            .attr('fill', function (d) { return d; });

        legendGroup.append('text')
          .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap-legend-text calendar-heatmap-legend-text-less')
          .attr('x', width - legendWidth - 13)
          .attr('y', height + SQUARE_LENGTH)
          .text(locale.Less);

        legendGroup.append('text')
          .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap-legend-text calendar-heatmap-legend-text-more')
          .attr('x', (width - legendWidth + SQUARE_PADDING) + (colorRange.length + 1) * 13)
          .attr('y', height + SQUARE_LENGTH)
          .text(locale.More);
      }

      dayRects.exit().remove();
      var monthLabels = svg.selectAll('.month')
          .data(monthRange)
          .enter().append('text')
          .attr('class', 'month-name')
          .style()
          .text(function (d) {
            return locale.months[d.getMonth()];
          })
          .attr('x', function (d, i) {
            var matchIndex = 0;
            dateRange.find(function (element, index) {
              matchIndex = index;
              return moment(d).isSame(element, 'month') && moment(d).isSame(element, 'year');
            });

            return Math.floor(matchIndex / 7) * (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING);
          })
          .attr('y', 0);  // fix these to the top

      locale.days.forEach(function (day, index) {
        index = formatWeekday(index);
        if (index % 2) {
          svg.append('text')
            .attr('class', 'day-initial')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(-8,' + (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING) * (index + 1) + ')')
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('dy', '2')
            .text(day);
        }
      });
    }

    function pluralizedTooltipUnit (count) {
      if ('string' === typeof tooltipUnit) {
        return (tooltipUnit + (count === 1 ? '' : 's'));
      }
      for (var i in tooltipUnit) {
        var _rule = tooltipUnit[i];
        var _min = _rule.min;
        var _max = _rule.max || _rule.min;
        _max = _max === 'Infinity' ? Infinity : _max;
        if (count >= _min && count <= _max) {
          return _rule.unit;
        }
      }
    }

    function tooltipHTMLForDate(d) {
      var dateStr = moment(d).format('ddd, MMM Do YYYY');
      var count = countForDate(d);
      return '<span><strong>' + (count ? count : locale.No) + ' ' + pluralizedTooltipUnit(count) + '</strong> ' + locale.on + ' ' + dateStr + '</span>';
    }

    function countForDate(d) {
      var count = 0;
      var match = chart.data().find(function (element, index) {
        return moment(element.date).isSame(d, 'day');
      });
      if (match) {
        count = match.count;
      }
      return count;
    }

    function formatWeekday(weekDay) {
      if (weekStart === 1) {
        if (weekDay === 0) {
          return 6;
        } else {
          return weekDay - 1;
        }
      }
      return weekDay;
    }

    var daysOfChart = chart.data().map(function (day) {
      return day.date.toDateString();
    });

    dayRects.filter(function (d) {
      return daysOfChart.indexOf(d.toDateString()) > -1;
    }).attr('fill', function (d, i) {
      return color(chart.data()[i].count);
    });
  }

  return chart;
}


// polyfill for Array.find() method
/* jshint ignore:start */
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function (predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}

var now = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
var yearAgo = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'year').toDate();
var chartData = d3.time.days(yearAgo, now).map(function (dateElement) {
  return {
    date: dateElement,
    count: (dateElement.getDay() !== 0 && dateElement.getDay() !== 6) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) : Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  };
});

var heatmap = calendarHeatmap()
                .data(chartData)
                .selector('.container')
                .tooltipEnabled(true)
                .colorRange(['#f4f7f7', '#79a8a9'])
                .onClick(function (data) {
                  console.log('data', data);
                });
heatmap();  // render the chart
```

```css
text.month-name,
text.calendar-heatmap-legend-text,
text.day-initial {
  font-size: 10px;
  fill: inherit;
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
rect.day-cell:hover {
  stroke: #555555;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.day-cell-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.day-cell-tooltip > span {
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, 'Open Sans', sans-serif
}
.calendar-heatmap {
  box-sizing: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here is plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JUBIs2IzHA9i5V8N1WMv?p=preview

```
var heatmap = calendarHeatmap()
                  .data(chartData)
                  .selector('.container')
                  .tooltipEnabled(true)
                  .colorRange(['#f4f7f7', '#79a8a9'])
                  .onClick(function (data) {
                    console.log('data', data);
                  });
```

I haven't made any changes to the original source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function calendarHeatmap() {
  // defaults
  var width = 750;
  var height = 110;
  var legendWidth = 150;
  var selector = 'body';
  var SQUARE_LENGTH = 11;
  var SQUARE_PADDING = 2;
  var MONTH_LABEL_PADDING = 6;
  var now = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
  var yearAgo = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'year').toDate();
  var startDate = null;
  var data = [];
  var max = null;
  var colorRange = ['#D8E6E7', '#218380'];
  var tooltipEnabled = true;
  var tooltipUnit = 'contribution';
  var legendEnabled = true;
  var onClick = null;
  var weekStart = 0; //0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday
  var locale = {
    months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    days: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    No: 'No',
    on: 'on',
    Less: 'Less',
    More: 'More'
  };

  // setters and getters
  chart.data = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return data; }
    data = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.max = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return max; }
    max = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.selector = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return selector; }
    selector = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.startDate = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return startDate; }
    yearAgo = value;
    now = moment(value).endOf('day').add(1, 'year').toDate();
    return chart;
  };

  chart.colorRange = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return colorRange; }
    colorRange = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.tooltipEnabled = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return tooltipEnabled; }
    tooltipEnabled = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.tooltipUnit = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return tooltipUnit; }
    tooltipUnit = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.legendEnabled = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return legendEnabled; }
    legendEnabled = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.onClick = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return onClick(); }
    onClick = value;
    return chart;
  };

  chart.locale = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return locale; }
    locale = value;
    return chart;
  };

  function chart() {

    d3.select(chart.selector()).selectAll('svg.calendar-heatmap').remove(); // remove the existing chart, if it exists

    var dateRange = d3.time.days(yearAgo, now); // generates an array of date objects within the specified range
    var monthRange = d3.time.months(moment(yearAgo).startOf('month').toDate(), now); // it ignores the first month if the 1st date is after the start of the month
    var firstDate = moment(dateRange[0]);
    if (max === null) { max = d3.max(chart.data(), function (d) { return d.count; }); } // max data value

    // color range
    var color = d3.scale.linear()
      .range(chart.colorRange())
      .domain([0, max]);

    var tooltip;
    var dayRects;

    drawChart();

    function drawChart() {
      var svg = d3.select(chart.selector())
        .style('position', 'relative')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap')
        .attr('height', height+SQUARE_LENGTH+SQUARE_LENGTH)
        .style('padding', '36px')
        .attr("transform","translate("+(SQUARE_LENGTH+4)+","+(SQUARE_LENGTH)+")");

      dayRects = svg.selectAll('.day-cell')
        .data(dateRange);  //  array of days for the last yr

      dayRects.enter().append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'day-cell')
        .attr('width', SQUARE_LENGTH)
        .attr('height', SQUARE_LENGTH)
        .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(countForDate(d)); })
        .attr('x', function (d, i) {
          var cellDate = moment(d);
          var result = cellDate.week() - firstDate.week() + (firstDate.weeksInYear() * (cellDate.weekYear() - firstDate.weekYear()));
          return result * (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING);
        })
        .attr('y', function (d, i) {
          return MONTH_LABEL_PADDING + formatWeekday(d.getDay()) * (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING);
        });

      if (typeof onClick === 'function') {
        dayRects.on('click', function (d) {
          var count = countForDate(d);
          onClick({ date: d, count: count});
        });
      }

      if (chart.tooltipEnabled()) {
        dayRects.on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
          tooltip = d3.select(chart.selector())
            .append('div')
            .attr('class', 'day-cell-tooltip')
            .html(tooltipHTMLForDate(d))
            .style('left', function () { return Math.floor(i / 7) * SQUARE_LENGTH + 'px'; })
            .style('top', function () {
              return formatWeekday(d.getDay()) * (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING) + MONTH_LABEL_PADDING * 2 + 'px';
            });
        })
        .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
          tooltip.remove();
        });
      }

      if (chart.legendEnabled()) {
        var colorRange = [color(0)];
        for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
          colorRange.push(color(max / i));
        }

        var legendGroup = svg.append('g');
        legendGroup.selectAll('.calendar-heatmap-legend')
            .data(colorRange)
            .enter()
          .append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap-legend')
            .attr('width', SQUARE_LENGTH)
            .attr('height', SQUARE_LENGTH)
            .attr('x', function (d, i) { return (width - legendWidth) + (i + 1) * 13; })
            .attr('y', height + SQUARE_PADDING)
            .attr('fill', function (d) { return d; });

        legendGroup.append('text')
          .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap-legend-text calendar-heatmap-legend-text-less')
          .attr('x', width - legendWidth - 13)
          .attr('y', height + SQUARE_LENGTH)
          .text(locale.Less);

        legendGroup.append('text')
          .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap-legend-text calendar-heatmap-legend-text-more')
          .attr('x', (width - legendWidth + SQUARE_PADDING) + (colorRange.length + 1) * 13)
          .attr('y', height + SQUARE_LENGTH)
          .text(locale.More);
      }

      dayRects.exit().remove();
      var monthLabels = svg.selectAll('.month')
          .data(monthRange)
          .enter().append('text')
          .attr('class', 'month-name')
          .style()
          .text(function (d) {
            return locale.months[d.getMonth()];
          })
          .attr('x', function (d, i) {
            var matchIndex = 0;
            dateRange.find(function (element, index) {
              matchIndex = index;
              return moment(d).isSame(element, 'month') && moment(d).isSame(element, 'year');
            });

            return Math.floor(matchIndex / 7) * (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING);
          })
          .attr('y', 0);  // fix these to the top

      locale.days.forEach(function (day, index) {
        index = formatWeekday(index);
        if (index % 2) {
          svg.append('text')
            .attr('class', 'day-initial')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(-8,' + (SQUARE_LENGTH + SQUARE_PADDING) * (index + 1) + ')')
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('dy', '2')
            .text(day);
        }
      });
    }

    function pluralizedTooltipUnit (count) {
      if ('string' === typeof tooltipUnit) {
        return (tooltipUnit + (count === 1 ? '' : 's'));
      }
      for (var i in tooltipUnit) {
        var _rule = tooltipUnit[i];
        var _min = _rule.min;
        var _max = _rule.max || _rule.min;
        _max = _max === 'Infinity' ? Infinity : _max;
        if (count >= _min && count <= _max) {
          return _rule.unit;
        }
      }
    }

    function tooltipHTMLForDate(d) {
      var dateStr = moment(d).format('ddd, MMM Do YYYY');
      var count = countForDate(d);
      return '<span><strong>' + (count ? count : locale.No) + ' ' + pluralizedTooltipUnit(count) + '</strong> ' + locale.on + ' ' + dateStr + '</span>';
    }

    function countForDate(d) {
      var count = 0;
      var match = chart.data().find(function (element, index) {
        return moment(element.date).isSame(d, 'day');
      });
      if (match) {
        count = match.count;
      }
      return count;
    }

    function formatWeekday(weekDay) {
      if (weekStart === 1) {
        if (weekDay === 0) {
          return 6;
        } else {
          return weekDay - 1;
        }
      }
      return weekDay;
    }

    var daysOfChart = chart.data().map(function (day) {
      return day.date.toDateString();
    });

    dayRects.filter(function (d) {
      return daysOfChart.indexOf(d.toDateString()) > -1;
    }).attr('fill', function (d, i) {
      return color(chart.data()[i].count);
    });
  }

  return chart;
}


// polyfill for Array.find() method
/* jshint ignore:start */
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function (predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}

var now = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
var yearAgo = moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'year').toDate();
var chartData = d3.time.days(yearAgo, now).map(function (dateElement) {
  return {
    date: dateElement,
    count: (dateElement.getDay() !== 0 && dateElement.getDay() !== 6) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) : Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
  };
});

var heatmap = calendarHeatmap()
                .data(chartData)
                .selector('.container')
                .tooltipEnabled(true)
                .colorRange(['#f4f7f7', '#79a8a9'])
                .onClick(function (data) {
                  console.log('data', data);
                });
heatmap();  // render the chart
```

```css
text.month-name,
text.calendar-heatmap-legend-text,
text.day-initial {
  font-size: 10px;
  fill: inherit;
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
rect.day-cell:hover {
  stroke: #555555;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.day-cell-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  color: #bbbbbb;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.day-cell-tooltip > span {
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, 'Open Sans', sans-serif
}
.calendar-heatmap {
  box-sizing: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

After analyzing here and there I figured it out why we are unable to see the legends and Month Lables, I'll explain below,
there is a problem with svg height and we need to move svg a little, the code change I've done is

```
var svg = d3.select(chart.selector())
        .style('position', 'relative')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('class', 'calendar-heatmap')
        .attr('height', height+SQUARE_LENGTH+SQUARE_LENGTH)
        .style('padding', '36px')
        .attr("transform","translate("+(SQUARE_LENGTH+4)+","+(SQUARE_LENGTH)+")");
```

Month lables are rendering but they are at some other point of svg, so I'm moving whole svg a little in calendar-heatmap.js while creating svg. This is the actual problem.
Initially I was also struggled to figure it out.well We solved it.
:D